# How to autowire service which in turn autowires another service in Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, autowired, applicationcontext

**TestSomething.class :**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "application-context-junit" })
public class TestSomething {

      @Autowired
      ISomeService someService;
      ...// more code 

}
```

**SomeServiceImpl.class :**

```
@Service("someService")
public class SomeServiceImpl implements ISomeService{
    @Autowired
    ISomeAnotherService someAnotherService;
    ..//more code
}
```

**application-context-junit.xml :**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.basepackage.*" />
```

So, my question is **Is it enough if I provide component-scan in application-context-junit.xml to handle all Autowires or should I add following to the xml as well?**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.basepackage.*" />
<bean id="someService" class=""com.basepackage.SomeServiceImpl"" />
<bean id="someAnotherService" class=""com.basepackage.SomeAnotherServiceImpl"" />
```

Comment: Why are you using a separate config for testing instead of using your existing configuration? If the service are annotated you only need the component-scanning. But if you only want to test the service (and don't really need spring for that) then just create an instance of the services and inject them yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the response. I have created separate config just for the purpose of understanding. The service I want to test has lots of autowires in it. So I need Spring here

Comment: It should work with just the component scan provided your impl of `ISomeAnotherService` is also properly annotated, e.g. with `@Component` or `@Service` or similar.  A word of advice though; avoid having large test contexts as these become their own maintenance burden and can become complex quickly.  I've found other projects where test were being run against stubs, and naively passing as a result of this.

Answer (score -1):

Every Time You Use Field Injection, a Unit Test Dies!

Don't use filed injection because it's not a good practice. Also when Spring has to Inject the classes for every test it will slow down the tests.

As you can read in this [Article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-di-patterns-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly) it's better to use constructor or setter injection.

This types of injections make it easy to mock the all the components which are used by the component under test, like the following:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class MyBeanTest {
    private MyBean target = new MyBean();
    private AnotherBean anotherBean = Mockito.mock(AnotherBean.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        myBean.setAnotherBean(anotherBean);
    }

    //Tests...
}
```

Comment: If you need an integration test instead of a unit test your approach won't work. Also Spring will cache contexts between runs so injection doesn't occur for every test only when the config changes (which shouldn't be that often when writing an integration test).

Comment: @Sebastian I'm interested in doing it without Mockito

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right if you want to write an integration test you need the Spring Framework to inject all the dependencies. But my approach with using constructor or setter injection is correct, because normally you are writing unit tests and integration tests.